# Pass variables to Ruby script via command line

Tags: ruby, command-line

I've installed RubyInstaller on Windows and I'm running [IMAP Sync](http://wonko.com/post/ruby_script_to_sync_email_from_any_imap_server_to_gmail) but I need to use it to sync hundreds of accounts. If I could pass these variables to it via command line I could automate the whole process better.

```
# Source server connection info.
SOURCE_NAME = 'username@example.com'
SOURCE_HOST = 'mail.example.com'
SOURCE_PORT = 143
SOURCE_SSL  = false
SOURCE_USER = 'username'
SOURCE_PASS = 'password'

# Destination server connection info.
DEST_NAME = 'username@gmail.com'
DEST_HOST = 'imap.gmail.com'
DEST_PORT = 993
DEST_SSL  = true
DEST_USER = 'username@gmail.com'
DEST_PASS = 'password'
```

Comment: You may want to consider editing this popular question into an actual *question*.

Answer (score 506, accepted):

Something like this:

```
ARGV.each do|a|
  puts "Argument: #{a}"
end
```

then

```
$ ./test.rb "test1 test2"
```

or

```
v1 = ARGV[0]
v2 = ARGV[1]
puts v1       #prints test1
puts v2       #prints test2
```

Comment: I would like to explicitly point out that ARGV[0] does not point to the program name, as some other languages do. To get the program name, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4834821/how-can-i-get-the-name-of-the-command-called-for-usage-prompts-in-ruby

Comment: Isn't `"test1 test2" just a single argument?

Comment: You need to add `#!/usr/bin/env ruby` on top of `.rb` file to be able to run it like this: `./test.rb`

Answer (score 207):

Don't reinvent the wheel; check out Ruby's way-cool [OptionParser](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/optparse/rdoc/OptionParser.html) library.

It offers parsing of flags/switches, parameters with optional or required values, can parse lists of parameters into a single option and can generate your help for you.

Also, if any of your information being passed in is pretty static, that doesn't change between runs, put it into a YAML file that gets parsed. That way you can have things that change every time on the command-line, and things that change occasionally configured outside your code. That separation of data and code is nice for maintenance.

Here are some samples to play with:

```
require 'optparse'
require 'yaml'

options = {}
OptionParser.new do |opts|
  opts.banner = "Usage: example.rb [options]"

  opts.on('-n', '--sourcename NAME', 'Source name') { |v| options[:source_name] = v }
  opts.on('-h', '--sourcehost HOST', 'Source host') { |v| options[:source_host] = v }
  opts.on('-p', '--sourceport PORT', 'Source port') { |v| options[:source_port] = v }

end.parse!

dest_options = YAML.load_file('destination_config.yaml')
puts dest_options['dest_name']
```

This is a sample YAML file if your destinations are pretty static:

```
--- 
dest_name: username@gmail.com
dest_host: imap.gmail.com
dest_port: 993
dest_ssl: true
dest_user: username@gmail.com
dest_pass: password
```

This will let you easily generate a YAML file:

```
require 'yaml'

yaml = {
  'dest_name' => 'username@gmail.com',
  'dest_host' => 'imap.gmail.com',
  'dest_port' => 993,
  'dest_ssl'  => true,
  'dest_user' => 'username@gmail.com',
  'dest_pass' => 'password'
}

puts YAML.dump(yaml)
```

Comment: OptParse link is dead. Try http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/optparse/rdoc/OptionParser.html

Comment: Excellent answer; may be worth adding that after option-parsing is done, `ARGV` contains only the operands, if any (that is, the remaining, NON-option arguments).

Answer (score 30):

Unfortunately, Ruby does not support such passing mechanism as e.g. AWK:

```
> awk -v a=1 'BEGIN {print a}'
> 1
```

It means you cannot pass named values into your script directly.

Using cmd options may help:

```
> ruby script.rb val_0 val_1 val_2

# script.rb
puts ARGV[0] # => val_0
puts ARGV[1] # => val_1
puts ARGV[2] # => val_2
```

Ruby stores all cmd arguments in the `ARGV` array, the scriptname itself can be captured using the `$PROGRAM_NAME` variable.

The obvious disadvantage is that you depend on the order of values.

If you need only Boolean switches use the option `-s` of the Ruby interpreter:

```
> ruby -s -e 'puts "So do I!" if $agreed' -- -agreed
> So do I!
```

Please note the `--` switch, otherwise Ruby will complain about a nonexistent option `-agreed`, so pass it as a switch to your cmd invokation. You don't need it in the following case:

```
> ruby -s script_with_switches.rb -agreed
> So do I!
```

The disadvantage is that you mess with global variables and have only logical true/false values.

You can access values from environment variables:

```
> FIRST_NAME='Andy Warhol' ruby -e 'puts ENV["FIRST_NAME"]'
> Andy Warhol
```

Drawbacks are present here to, you have to set all the variables before the script invocation (only for your ruby process) or to export them (shells like BASH):

```
> export FIRST_NAME='Andy Warhol'
> ruby -e 'puts ENV["FIRST_NAME"]'
```

In the latter case, your data will be readable for everybody in the same shell session and for all subprocesses, which can be a serious security implication.

And at least you can implement an option parser using [getoptlong](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/getoptlong/rdoc/index.html) and [optparse](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/optparse/rdoc/index.html).

Happy hacking!

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

I know this is old, but **getoptlong** wasn't mentioned here and it's probably the best way to parse command line arguments today.

---

### Parsing command line arguments

I strongly recommend [getoptlong](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/getoptlong/rdoc/GetoptLong.html). It's pretty easy to use and works like a charm.
Here is an example extracted from the link above

```
require 'getoptlong'

opts = GetoptLong.new(
    [ '--help', '-h', GetoptLong::NO_ARGUMENT ],
    [ '--repeat', '-n', GetoptLong::REQUIRED_ARGUMENT ],
    [ '--name', GetoptLong::OPTIONAL_ARGUMENT ]
)

dir = nil
name = nil
repetitions = 1
opts.each do |opt, arg|
    case opt
        when '--help'
            puts <<-EOF
hello [OPTION] ... DIR

-h, --help:
     show help

--repeat x, -n x:
     repeat x times

--name [name]:
     greet user by name, if name not supplied default is John

DIR: The directory in which to issue the greeting.
            EOF
        when '--repeat'
            repetitions = arg.to_i
        when '--name'
            if arg == ''
                name = 'John'
            else
                name = arg
            end
    end
end

if ARGV.length != 1
    puts "Missing dir argument (try --help)"
    exit 0
end

dir = ARGV.shift

Dir.chdir(dir)
for i in (1..repetitions)
    print "Hello"
    if name
        print ", #{name}"
    end
    puts
end
```

You can call it like this
`ruby hello.rb -n 6 --name -- /tmp`

### What OP is trying to do

In this case I think the best option is to use YAML files as suggested [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4248426/1423901)

Answer (score 1):

You can also try out `cliqr`. Its pretty new and in active development. But there are stable releases ready to be used. Here is the git repo: https://github.com/anshulverma/cliqr

Look into the example folder to get an idea on how it can be used.

Answer (score 0):

Run this code on the command line and enter the value of N:

```
N  = gets; 1.step(N.to_i, 1) { |i| print "hello world\n" }
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless it is the most trivial case, there is only one sane way to use command line options in Ruby. It is called [docopt](https://github.com/docopt/docopt.rb) and documented [here](http://docopt.org/).

What is amazing with it, is it's simplicity. **All you have to do, is specify the "help" text for your command.** What you write there will then be auto-parsed by the *standalone* (!) ruby library.

From the [example](https://github.com/docopt/docopt.rb/blob/master/examples/counted_example.rb):

```rb
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'docopt.rb'

doc = <<DOCOPT
Usage: #{__FILE__} --help
       #{__FILE__} -v...
       #{__FILE__} go [go]
       #{__FILE__} (--path=<path>)...
       #{__FILE__} <file> <file>

Try: #{__FILE__} -vvvvvvvvvv
     #{__FILE__} go go
     #{__FILE__} --path ./here --path ./there
     #{__FILE__} this.txt that.txt

DOCOPT

begin
  require "pp"
  pp Docopt::docopt(doc)
rescue Docopt::Exit => e
  puts e.message
end
```

The output:

```sh
$ ./counted_example.rb -h
Usage: ./counted_example.rb --help
       ./counted_example.rb -v...
       ./counted_example.rb go [go]
       ./counted_example.rb (--path=<path>)...
       ./counted_example.rb <file> <file>

Try: ./counted_example.rb -vvvvvvvvvv
     ./counted_example.rb go go
     ./counted_example.rb --path ./here --path ./there
     ./counted_example.rb this.txt that.txt

$ ./counted_example.rb something else
{"--help"=>false,
 "-v"=>0,
 "go"=>0,
 "--path"=>[],
 "<file>"=>["something", "else"]}

$ ./counted_example.rb -v
{"--help"=>false, "-v"=>1, "go"=>0, "--path"=>[], "<file>"=>[]}

$ ./counted_example.rb go go
{"--help"=>false, "-v"=>0, "go"=>2, "--path"=>[], "<file>"=>[]}
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

You should try [console_runner](https://github.com/yuri-karpovich/console_runner) gem. This gem makes your pure Ruby code executable from command-line. All you need is to add [YARD](https://yardoc.org/) annotations to your code:

```
# @runnable This tool can talk to you. Run it when you are lonely.
#   Written in Ruby.  
class MyClass

    def initialize
      @hello_msg = 'Hello' 
      @bye_msg = 'Good Bye' 
    end

    # @runnable Say 'Hello' to you.
    # @param [String] name Your name
    # @param [Hash] options options
    # @option options [Boolean] :second_meet Have you met before?
    # @option options [String] :prefix Your custom prefix
    def say_hello(name, options = {})
      second_meet = nil
      second_meet = 'Nice to see you again!' if options['second_meet']
      prefix = options['prefix']
      message = @hello_msg + ', '
      message += "#{prefix} " if prefix
      message += "#{name}. "
      message += second_meet if second_meet
      puts message
    end

end
```

Then run it from console:

```
$ c_run /projects/example/my_class.rb  say_hello -n John --second-meet --prefix Mr. 
-> Hello, Mr. John. Nice to see you again!
```