# How can I get the name of the command called for usage prompts in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, command-line

I wrote a nice little Ruby script a while back that I'm rather fond of. I'd like to improve its robustness by checking for the proper number of arguments:

```
if ARGV.length != 2 then
  puts "Usage: <command> arg1 arg2"
end
```

Of course that's pseudocode. Anyways, in C or C++ I could use `argv[0]` to get the name that the user used to get to my command, whether they called it like `./myScript.rb` or `myScript.rb` or `/usr/local/bin/myScript.rb`. In Ruby, I know that `ARGV[0]` is the first true argument, and `ARGV` does not contain the command name. Is there any way that I can get this?

Answer (score 161, accepted):

Ruby has three ways of giving us the name of the called script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

puts "$0            : #{$0}"
puts "__FILE__      : #{__FILE__}"
puts "$PROGRAM_NAME : #{$PROGRAM_NAME}"
```

Saving that code as "test.rb" and calling it a couple ways shows that the script receives the name as it was passed to it by the OS. A script only knows what the OS tells it:

```
$ ./test.rb 
$0            : ./test.rb
__FILE__      : ./test.rb
$PROGRAM_NAME : ./test.rb

$ ~/Desktop/test.rb 
$0            : /Users/ttm/Desktop/test.rb
__FILE__      : /Users/ttm/Desktop/test.rb
$PROGRAM_NAME : /Users/ttm/Desktop/test.rb

$ /Users/ttm/Desktop/test.rb 
$0            : /Users/ttm/Desktop/test.rb
__FILE__      : /Users/ttm/Desktop/test.rb
$PROGRAM_NAME : /Users/ttm/Desktop/test.rb
```

Calling it using the `~` shortcut for $HOME in the second example shows the OS replacing it with the expanded path, matching what is in the third example. In all cases it's what the OS passed in.

Linking to the file using both hard and soft links shows consistent behavior. I created a hard link for test1.rb and a soft link for test2.rb:

```
$ ./test1.rb 
$0            : ./test1.rb
__FILE__      : ./test1.rb
$PROGRAM_NAME : ./test1.rb

$ ./test2.rb 
$0            : ./test2.rb
__FILE__      : ./test2.rb
$PROGRAM_NAME : ./test2.rb
```

Launching `ruby test.rb` with any of the variations on the script name returns consistent results.

If you only want the called filename, you can use File's `basename` method with one of the variables or split on the delimiter and take the last element.

`$0` and `__FILE__` have some minor differences but for single scripts they're equivalent.

```
puts File.basename($0)
```

There are some benefits to using the `File.basename`,`File.extname` and `File.dirname` suite of methods. `basename` takes an optional parameter, which is the extension to strip, so if you need just the basename without the extension

```
File.basename($0, File.extname($0))
```

does it without reinventing the wheel or having to deal with variable-length or missing extensions or the possibility of incorrectly truncating extension chains "`.rb.txt`" for instance:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :004 > filename = '/path/to/file/name.ext'
 => "/path/to/file/name.ext" 
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :005 > File.basename(filename, File.extname(filename))
 => "name" 
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :006 > filename = '/path/to/file/name.ext' << '.txt'
 => "/path/to/file/name.ext.txt" 
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :007 > File.basename(filename, File.extname(filename))
 => "name.ext"
```

Comment: Thanks for the very complete answer!

Comment: Note that there is different behavior if you use the suggested options in an included script using 'require' or 'require_relative. Using $0 and $PROGRAM_NAME return the name of the calling script. Using the FILE option with surrounding double underbars (How do you format that in a comment?) returns the name of the included script.

Comment: Slight nit, `~` gets expanded by the shell, not the OS. `~/thing` is a valid relative path to a directory named `~` with a directory or file named `thing`

Answer (score 18):

this answer might come a bit late, but I have had the same issue and the accepted answer didn't seem quite satisfying to me, so I investigated a bit further.

What bothered me was the fact that `$0` or `$PROGRAM_NAME` did not really hold the correct information about what the user had **typed**. If my Ruby script was in a PATH folder and the user entered the executable name (without any path definitions such as `./script` or `/bin/script`), it would always expand to the total path.

I thought this was a Ruby deficite, so I tried the same with Python and to my chagrin there, it was no different.

A friend suggested me a hack to look for the `real thing` in `/proc/self/cmdline`, and the result was: `[ruby, /home/danyel/bin/myscript, arg1, arg2...]` (separated by the null-char). The villain here is `execve(1)` which expands the path to the total path when it passes it to an interpreter.

Example C program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

extern char** environ;
int main() {
  char ** arr = malloc(10 * sizeof(char*));
  arr[0] = "myscript";
  arr[1] = "-h";
  arr[2] = NULL;
  execve("/home/danyel/bin/myscript", arr, environ);
}
```

Output: `Usage: /home/danyel/bin/myscript FILE...

To prove that this is indeed a `execve` thing and not from bash, we can create a dummy interpreter that does nothing but print out the arguments passed to it:

```
// interpreter.c
int main(int argc, const char ** argv) {
  while(*argv)
    printf("%s\n", *(argv++));
}
```

We compile it and put it in a path folder (or put the full path after the shebang) and create a dummy script in `~/bin/myscript/`

```
#!/usr/bin/env interpreter
Hi there!
```

Now, in our main.c:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

extern char** environ;
int main() {
  char ** arr = malloc(10 * sizeof(char*));
  arr[0] = "This will be totally ignored by execve.";
  arr[1] = "-v";
  arr[2] = "/var/log/apache2.log";
  arr[3] = NULL;
  execve("/home/danyel/bin/myscript", arr, environ);
}
```

Compiling and running `./main`:
    interpreter
    /home/danyel/bin/myscript
    -v
    /var/log/apache2.log

The reason behind this most likely is that if the script is in your PATH and the full path were **not** provided, the interpreter would recognize this as a `No such file` error, which it does if you do: `ruby myrubyscript --options arg1` and you're not in the folder with that script.

Answer (score 3):

Use `$0`or `$PROGRAM_NAME` to get the file name that is currently being executed.

Comment: This gives me the complete path. I would like to know what the user entered. For example, if I have `/usr/local/bin/myScript` and `/usr/local/bin` is in my `$PATH`, and I just type `myScript`, I get `/usr/local/bin/myScript` from `$0`

Comment: How about `$0.split("/").last` ?

Comment: I'm not asking for JUST the program name, what I mean is that I want exactly what the user typed in to run the program. If they typed `./myScript`, I want a variable that gives me `./myScript`. If they typed `/usr/bin/local/myScript`, I want exactly that. etc.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't quite an answer to your question, but it sounds like you're reinventing a wheel. Look at the [optparse](http://stdlib.rubyonrails.org/libdoc/optparse/rdoc/index.html) library. It lets you define command line switches, arguments, etc, and it'll do all the heavy lifting for you.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't need anything that complicated. I mean, I only have 2 arguments, so it's too simple a case to warrant all that.