# Individual log file per file in ruby file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging

Consider there are 5 ruby files as listed below in one gem:-

```
1. file1.rb
2. file2.rb
3. file3.rb
4. file4.rb
5. file5.rb
```

Each file contains list of action/methods in it as listed here.

In file1.rb

```
Class File1

def method1
end

def method2
end

end
```

1. When i call method1 and method2 or any other methods from file1.rb from my application to the gem via class name.
2. When i call method1 and method2 or any other methods from file2.rb from my application to the gem via class name.

I want to log the request, repsonse to be in a separate file for each class (calssname =File1)

How can i do it from my application to the gem.

Note:-  I have gem source files with me.

Comment: possible dupplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4834821/how-can-i-get-the-name-of-the-command-called-for-usage-prompts-in-ruby

Comment: @PedroMorteRolo I have edited the questions. Kindly look at it.