# Pass a dos variable to a ruby script from a dos batch file

Tags: ruby, batch-file, dos

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Pass variables to ruby script via command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244611/pass-variables-to-ruby-script-via-command-line)

I am trying to pass the HOSTNAME as a parameter into a ruby script.  Is this possible? This is what I believe should work, but it doesn't.

```
%h% = HOSTNAME
ECHO %h%

ruby this.rb %h%
pause
```

And the ruby code is

```
val = ARGV[0]

puts "Value is #{val}"
```

Comment: I believe you don't have to put the `%` signs.

Comment: @Eitan, No it's not a duplicate.

Comment: @MurifoX. If you don't put the % signs the ruby puts returns "Value is h"

Comment: @Andrew Ok, so what output do you get? And what if you do `ruby this.rb "something"` instead? Would the ruby script then print "Value is something"?

Comment: Ruby is not able access that via ENV?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set an environment variable in DOS and access it from your Ruby script.  It would be something like:

```
set h = HOSTNAME
ECHO %h%

ruby this.rb
pause
```

Ruby code:

```
val = ENV["h"]

puts "Value is #{val}"
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid that. The actual script with the problem was : ruby replace_text.rb myfile.csv A_Computer_Name HOSTNAME