# How to edit a *nix system file using Ruby's File.open command?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux

In my CMS (Rails 4), I need to let a user make CRUD processes on CIFS mount points. In order to have a permanent CIFS mount on a CentOS (6) system, I need to edit the `/etc/fstab` file and update the mount list with the `sudo mount -a` command. When I try to open `/etc/fstab` file with `File.open`:

```
File.open("/etc/fstab", "a") do |f|
  f.puts "\n test"
end
```

I get this error:

```
Errno::EACCES: Permission denied - /etc/fstab
```

It's normal because `/etc/fstab` file belongs to the root user. Is there a way to open a file as super user? At the other hand, I'm open to different ideas. My requirement is to edit the fstab file from inside of my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this [answer](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/4405721) in the ruby forum:

> Start your script using
>
> ```
> sudo ruby myscript.rb
> ```
>
> You can't gain root privileges mid-script, short of
>
> ```
> system("sudo ruby anotherscript.rb")
> ```

Comment: What If I need to use dynamic parameters in that script? :\ I need to use `params[:path]` parameter.

Comment: `system("sudo ruby anotherscript.rb #{params[:path]}")`, http://stackoverflow.com/a/4244651/1120015

Answer (score 0):

This one is tricky but you could add your Web user to the sudoers list and submit the sudo password when trying to edit the file. Make sure your connection is secured via https