# How do I print Selenium Webdriver (Ruby binding) test results to a notepad file from command?

Tags: ruby, windows, automation, selenium-webdriver

I wish to put the text from command prompt into a text file once the test is run. How do we do that
?[image: Command Prompt]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a pipe `>`. Worth to look [Using command redirection operators](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx?mfr=true).

```
ruby test.rb > file.txt
```

**Redirection operator and description**

`>` : Writes the command output to a file or a device, such as a printer, instead of the Command Prompt window.

`<` : Reads the command input from a file, instead of reading input from the keyboard.

`>>` : Appends the command output to the end of a file without deleting the information that is already in the file.

`>&` : Writes the output from one handle to the input of another handle.

`<&` : Reads the input from one handle and writes it to the output of another handle.

`|` : Reads the output from one command and writes it to the input of another command. Also known as a pipe.

Comment: Great, also is there a way I can parameterize the inputs to script? Right now, I am sending keys like: - 

`browser.find_element(:xpath,"/html/body/div/input").send_keys"7.5",:tab`

I wish if there could be a way where this input could be picked up from an external file?

Comment: @user007 Check this out - [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244611/pass-variables-to-ruby-script-via-command-line) and [2](http://ruby.about.com/od/rubyfeatures/a/argv.htm)