# How to read parameter from Paramterized Build using ruby?

Tags: jenkins

I'm using [Paramterized Build](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build), and know I can get paramter by name in bash like `$name`.

But I want to write script with ruby, how can I get the paramter?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should be able to get them using env variables

http://ruby.about.com/od/rubyfeatures/a/envvar.htm

Comment: I have tested it but no luck.

Comment: can you post the output in the console?

Answer (score 0):

To send parameters to your ruby script, you may use the following way:

call the script and pass the parameters from the command line (for **Jenkins**, you may use execute shell script option)

`$ irb ruby_script.rb parameter1 parameter2`

and in ruby_script.rb, you can get these parameters by using builtin ruby syntax, ARGV:

`parameter_one = ARGV[0]   // refer to the first paramter
parameter_one = ARGV[1]   // refer to the second paramter`

You may refer to this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244611/pass-variables-to-ruby-script-via-command-line)