# How to pass URL in ruby command line?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have written a ruby program in which it takes the input as url and it displays the components in it.
I passed the URL inside the ruby file but now I want to pass it through ruby command line like ruby filename.rb url.
How to pass an argument inside the code.

Comment: I believe this should help you out.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244611/pass-variables-to-ruby-script-via-command-line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ARGV` constant holds an array which contains all of the arguments passed in on the command line. So in your script, you could get the url passed in via `ARGV[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

ARGV is an array which contains all the arguments passed into your script via the command line.

```
ARGV.each do|arg|
  puts "Argument: #{arg}"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `ARGV` constant , you can puts `ARGV.to_s` in log to see what`s in it , to helps you understand how to use it .