# OptionParser with subcommands

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to create a command line program with sub-commands using OptionParser. I'm following "[ruby's OptionParser to get subcommands](https://gist.github.com/rkumar/445735)".

The problem is that it does not allow for a use case like this:

```
ruby main.rb --version 
#=> main.rb in `<main>': undefined method `order!' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

But it does allow for this:

```
ruby main.rb foo --options
ruby main.rb --options foo
ruby main.rb --options foo --options
```

How would I be properly handle command line arguments, in the case that no subcommand is given.

My example code is:

```
global = OptionParser.new do |opts|
  opts.banner = "Usage: opt.rb [options] [subcommand [options]]"
  opts.on("-v", "--version", "Print the version") do |v|
    options[:version] = v
  end
  opts.separator ""
  opts.separator subtext
end
```

Comment: Can you add your actual code? The example you linked to does allow for your case of `ruby main.rb --version` so without seeing your code, we cannot debug the problem.

Comment: @jkeuhlen the code is exactly the same as the URL I posted, except "--verbose" is replaced with "--version", the point being that the code as is, will throw a `nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)` if it does not follow `program [[options] [subcommand] [options]]` format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lines with the error:

```
global.order!
command = ARGV.shift
subcommands[command].order!
```

If `global.order!` uses all of `ARGV`, then command is `nil`. So... check for that.

```
global.order!
command = ARGV.shift
unless command
  STDERR.puts "ERROR: no subcommand"
  STDERR.puts global # prints usage
  exit(-1)
end
subcommands[command].order!
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this'll help:

```
require 'optparse'

VERSION = '1.0.0'

options = {}
OptionParser.new do |opt|
  opt.on('-f', '--foo', 'Foo it') { |o| options[:foo] = o }

  opt.on_tail('-v', '--version') do
    puts VERSION
    exit
  end

end.parse!

puts options
```

Saving it as "test.rb" and running it with `ruby test.rb` returns:

```
{}
```

Running it with `ruby test.rb -f` or `--foo` returns:

```
{:foo=>true}
```

Running it with `ruby test.rb -v` or `--version` returns:

```
1.0.0
```

For more fun, running `ruby test.rb -h` or `--help` returns:

```
Usage: test [options]
    -f, --foo                        Foo it
```

even though I didn't define `-h` or `--help`.

If I wanted the `-v` and `--version` flags to appear in the list then I'd change them from a `on_tail` method to a normal `on` method:

```
require 'optparse'

VERSION = '1.0.0'

options = {}
OptionParser.new do |opt|
  opt.on('-f', '--foo', 'Foo it') { |o| options[:foo] = o }

  opt.on('-v', '--version', 'Returns the version') do
    puts VERSION
    exit
  end

end.parse!

puts options
```

which would return:

```
Usage: test [options]
    -f, --foo                        Foo it
    -v, --version                    Returns the version
```

I can add:

```
puts ARGV
```

to the end of the script and see that OptionParser is correctly handling flags and parameters:

```
>ruby test.rb bar --foo
{:foo=>true}
bar

>ruby test.rb --foo bar
{:foo=>true}
bar
```

See "[Pass variables to Ruby script via command line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4244611/128421)" for more information.

---

There is no way your example code will handle your sample inputs using `--options`. No handler for `--options` is defined. Nor is `subtext`. Your code returns:

```
undefined local variable or method `subtext' for main:Object (NameError)
```

Stripping the block to:

```
global = OptionParser.new do |opts|
  opts.on("-v", "--version", "Print the version") do |v|
    options[:version] = v
  end
end
```

and running again returns:

```
invalid option: --options (OptionParser::InvalidOption)
```

So, again, your example doesn't match the results you say you're getting.