# How to add a command to a ruby script for terminal in Kali linux?

Tags: ruby, shell, kali-linux

Noob question, but how do I add a command in a ruby script for the terminal?

for example `ruby tool.rb` and I want to add a command `-c` that will invoke a method that prints blah blah, and then execute it via the terminal in kali linux, so it would look something like this `ruby tool.rb -c`. Would anyone know how to do this and know what this is called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's called running a ruby script/program from the command line and passing "flags" like `-c` are passed to the script as command line arguments and are an array of string values separated by spaces normally.

Here's your very simple script:

#### tool.rb

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

if ARGV[0] == '-c'
  puts 'blah blah'
end
```

You can run this from the command line exactly as you requested.

```
ruby tool.rb -c
```

#### Updated

If you need additional arguments or want to pass something else to your flag you can do as I mentioned `ARGV` is an array constructed from string passed after the name of your ruby script so:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

if ARGV[0] == '-c'
  puts "blah blah #{ARGV[1]}" # array items are called by index
end
```

So if you do this:

```
ruby tool.rb -c foo
```

You will get:

```
blah blah foo
```

Comment: Thank you, one last question how would I add a value to the called flag e.g. `-c "some string or value"`?@lacostenycoder

Comment: everything after the name of your ruby script is interpreted as string input data in `ARGV`  for more info see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244611/pass-variables-to-ruby-script-via-command-line and  https://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/ARGF.html

Answer (score 0):

you can solve this with the help of **metaprogramming** and **hash**

```
def invoke
  puts "blah blah"
end

fun = {"-c": "invoke"}
send(fun[:"#{ARGV[0]}"])
```

in terminal

```
ruby tool.rb -c
```

*send* invokes private method also be cautious in using it

Hope, this is the solution you are looking for

Comment: this answer is a bit more complex that what the OP needs IMHO