# Passing command line arguments to ruby script using ARGV

Tags: ruby, jira, argv

how can I pass Jira Ticket-ID as a command-line argument to the ruby script? I'm using Jira-ruby gem. I have a script in which I have to find a particular Jira ticket and comment on it. I want to pass that ticket from the command line to the ruby script. Thanks in advance

```rb
jira_client.Issue.find("ID-10389")
    comment = issue.comments.build
    comment.save!(:body => "New comment from example script")`
end
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass variables to Ruby script via command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244611/pass-variables-to-ruby-script-via-command-line)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ARGV` that contains all string passed as an argument to the command line.

You may try something like this using a splat operator: `id, *the_rest = ARGV`.
Then you can use the local variable `id` to call the `jira_client.Issue.find` method.